# How to combine 2 javascript/jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

When it comes to Javascript/jquery, I'm still a bit of a newbie.

I've currently got a donation form with an html list in Wordpress.
The first 3 options are just fixed options (5 euro, 10 euro, 15 euro), but the last `<li>` option is a `"open"` option. When the last `<li>` is clicked, a hidden `input` field shows up where a user could type in a different value.

With Jquery I need these 2 functions :

- The first one is to set `<li>` to active when it is clicked. When a specific `<li>` is active, a hidden `input` field will be visible.
- The second one is to delete the first x character and the last x characters of the words inside the `<li>`.

These are the Jquery codes I'm currently using :

This one for the active `<li>` :

```
$(".donate-box ul li").click(function(){
  if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

This one for the characters :

```
$('.donate-box ul li').text(function (i,t) {
    return t.slice(0, -72);
    
});

$('.donate-box ul li').each(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.text( $th.text().substr(99) );
});
```

The both work separately, but when I add the second code (for the characters), the first one stops working properly. The `<li>` still gets active when clicked, but the hidden `input` field isn't showing up anymore. So something goes wrong.

Anybody that knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you're adding the second code inside the click event right?

Comment: You'll need to include your HTML.  It *looks like* you have your invisible input *inside* the `li`.  So when you use `.text(...)` it overwrites your invisible input so there's nothing there to show.

Comment: Share your HTML Please..

Comment: You are supposed to have an extrafield.. say a <span> within <li> whose text you'll overwrite because your current implementation overrides everything in<li> like @freedomn-m said

Comment: I will post the HTML, but it's from a plugin in Wordpress.

Comment: The html :

This is for the list options

    `<ul id="form_624_field_2" label="" class="" required="" style="list-style-type:none;margin:0;">
    <li>€ 5,00</li>
    <li>€ 10,00</li>
    <li>€ 15,00</li>
    <li>Anders </li>
    </ul>`

Comment: This is for the open option, which opens when "anders" is active
'<p id="rfmp_open_amount_624" style="display:none;">
                        <label>Bedrag 
                            <span style="color:red;">*</span><br>
                            <span class="rfmp_currency_624">€</span> 
                            <input type="number" step="any" value="" onchange="mollie_forms_624_totals();" name="rfmp_amount_624"> 
                        </label>
                        <input type="hidden"  id="rfmp_open_amount_required_624" value="0">
                      </p>'